# FaceBook Page Crawling

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, web-crawler

I was developing a social media aggregator and was wondering if there was a way to crawl FaceBook, Twitter and other social media networking sites, by using Java Code. I want to crawl specific data from FaceBook Pages. Do I require specific permissions from FaceBook or any other requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically yes... #2
https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms

If you're building it in Java as a Robot, I've had more success using JS and a local/remote webserver. Though this in theory is more easily detected

If you're building it as an essentially automated web browser as long as you rate limit yourself and add in a little random wait there is no good way of detecting it.

Comment: Thank You, do you have a code for the JS and a local server? Would render Helpful.

Comment: Can you please share your crawler?

Comment: https://github.com/vivekpatani/ai-ml-projects-data-science/tree/master/project-social-media-aggregator We are working on a newer version, which is much more efficient. Will keep you posted, we aim to get it ready next month. @kuhaku

Answer (score 1):

Yes according to https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php you need written permission from Facebook if you are going to crawl them.